# Split path name in android

Tags: android

I use Environment to take path from sdcard in android..

I have a folder path: `/mnt/sdcard/DNTarie/MalinKundang`

What i want is just take "MalinKundang" (the last name from folder path), how to do that?

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the `split` examples will work, perhaps using the `File` class is arguably "better", just in case you port the code to Windows or MacOS:

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/DNTarie/MalinKundag";
String fileName = new File(path).getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  String  ss = "/mnt/sdcard/DNTarie/MalinKundang";
  String[] arr = ss.split("/");
  System.out.println(ar[arr.length-1]);// Get last value in array
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/DNTarie/MalinKundag";
String stringYouWant = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"), path.length());
```

should do it

Comment: this is java or android?? because i can't using `string.substring()`..
but i tried to search using substring in android and yep.. it works..
i have my code like this: `mPath = path.substring(20);`.. it's simple..
thanks for answer my question.. :D